# Format syntax in Python

Tags: python, syntax, format

Is there a way to write this line of code in a better way :

```
"""{a};{b};{c};{d}""".format(a = myDictionary[a], b = myDictionary[b], c = myDictionary[c], d = myDictionary[d])
```

something like this ?

```
"""{a};{b};{c};{d}""".format(myDictionary)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [keyword expansion](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) on the dictionary:

```
"{a};{b};{c};{d}".format(**myDictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

`format` can dereference its parameters:

```
>>> D=dict(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
>>> '{0[a]};{0[b]};{0[c]};{0[d]}'.format(D)
'1;2;3;4'
```

A similar syntax can be used on classes:

```
>>> class C:
...  a=1
...  b=2
...  c=3
...  d=4
...
>>> '{0.a};{0.b};{0.c};{0.d}'.format(C)
'1;2;3;4'
```

See the [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec).

Answer (score 0):

```
"""%(a)s;%(b)s;%(c)s;%(d)s""" % myDictionary
```

Despite a lot of controversy and pushes, the traditional string formatting operator "%" has no motives (nor signs) to go away,a s a lot of things are simpler with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```
di = {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
  'key3': 'value3'
}

print "value of key3 is: %(key3)s" % di
```

> > > value of key3 is: value3